# Forcing all methods to throw Exception

Tags: java

I have lot of methods in a given class and these methods are called from a different class. Each method should throw Exceptions ideally so that they are handled from the main class.

Is there any way to force all methods to throw Exception if not done? In the below example, function2() does not throw Exception. What I would like to do is to force it.

```
public void function1() throws Exception {
   // Some Actions
}

public void function2() {
   // Some Actions
}
```

Comment: er... why can't you just use `throw new RuntimeException();`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense; if the method needs to throw a (checked) exception, it will specify it in its signature.  There should be no need to *force* it to.

Comment: just because the signature of function2 doesn't state it, doesn't mean that it can't throw an Exception.

Comment: @Stultuske: It can throw an *unchecked* exception, yes.

Comment: Checked or unchecked? Wrap an aspect around the class and throw it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can still throw [unchecked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) Exceptions without naming a `... method() throws Exception`.

However, if you want to throw checked exceptions, you would have to implement an interface:

```
interface Thrower {
    public void function1() throws Exception;
    public void function2() throws Exception;
}

class SomeClass implements Thrower {
    ...
}
```

While this is not an optimal solution, it is the only one that comes to my mind.

**It is not possible to declare that all methods of a class must throw an exception**.

Comment: Although this solution does not suit me, this clarifies my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Each method should throw Exceptions ideally so that they are handled
>   from the main class

If there are handled from the main class I think it's better to use a `RuntimeException` or an exception that extends from `RuntimeExeption`, in this is way you don't have to worry about `throw exception` ,because `RuntimeException` propagates automatically.